# Expected ";" before numeric constant

Tags: c++

My code is as follows

```
int s = 0, t = 0;
for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i *= 2) s += i;
 int p = 1, q = 50;
while(p < q) {
 t += 2 * p – 3 * q; p++; q /= 2;
}
 cout << s << " " << t;
```

Pretty simple but it keeps giving me and error saying what the title says and its on the "t += ..." line i really cant figure out why anybody got a suggestion to try or a solution?

Comment: Please add the error message

Comment: Looks like your `-` is a unicode character.

Comment: if you get error like that its a good start to simplify things and try getting to the location where the error happens from there on you can work yourself forward

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept the answer for further references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Non-[ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) character `–`. Use `-` instead.[image: Non-Ascii character] Compiles and runs successfully after that fix